# TypeScript variable seems not to load the value from one file to another

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am following the tutorial here: https://coursetro.com/posts/code/154/Angular-6-Tutorial---Learn-Angular-6-in-this-Crash-Course

I currently have the code up to the section titled **Fetching More Data from the API** working.  In short this is supposed to make a page with a bunch of users accessed through a toy API.  The users are listed on a page with some personal information, and each one links to a very basic profile page displaying their details.  Up to the section I mentioned above, I am successfully interfacing with the API, getting the users and displaying them and some personal information on the main page.

However, the code in this section is intended to collect an individual user's details and display them on a linked page. In trying to follow the example, my code does produce a page with the right outlines, but the value of the variable `user$` and its fields like `user$.name` don't seem to be loaded by the details component. Where those values are supposed to show up, it's blank.

**The app files:**

*app-routing.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { UsersComponent } from './users/users.component';
import { DetailsComponent } from './details/details.component';
import { PostsComponent } from './posts/posts.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: UsersComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'details/:id',
    component: DetailsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'posts',
    component: PostsComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

*app.component.html*

```
<div id="container">
  <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>

  <div id="content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

*app.module.ts*

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { PostsComponent } from './posts/posts.component';
import { UsersComponent } from './users/users.component';
import { DetailsComponent } from './details/details.component';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    PostsComponent,
    UsersComponent,
    DetailsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

*data.service.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUsers() {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  }

  getUser(userId) {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'+userId)
  }

  getPosts() {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  }
}
```

**users files:**

*users.component.html*

```
<h1>Users</h1>

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let user of users$">
    <a href="" routerLink="/details/{{ user.id }}">{{user.name}}</a>
    <ul>
      <li>{{user.email}}</li>
      <li><a href="http://{{user.website}}">{{user.website}}</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

*users.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.scss']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

  users$: Object;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.getUsers().subscribe(
      data => this.users$ = data
    );
  }

}
```

**details files:**

*details.component.html*

```
<h1>{{ user$.name }}</h1>

<ul>
  <li><strong>Username: </strong> {{user$.username}}</li>
  <li><strong>Email: </strong> {{user$.email}}</li>
  <li><strong>Phone: </strong> {{user$.phone}}</li>
</ul>
```

*details.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-details',
  templateUrl: './details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details.component.scss']
})
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  user$: Object;

  constructor(private data: DataService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.params.subscribe( params => this.user$ = params.id );
    console.log(this.route.params);
  }  

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.getUser(this.user$).subscribe(
      data => this.user$ = data
    );
  }

}
```

I tried logging values to the console, but I don't fully understand how TypeScript works so I don't fully know what I really should expect from these logs.  In any case, in the log that I made in the details TypeScript file, it showed an object with no apparent loading errors.

Answer (score 0):

this.route.params is a Observable. I am not sure what you can get by logging it.

I would suggest you add a log when subscribing to a observable and see what kind of data you really get. Like.

```
 this.data.getUser(this.user$).subscribe(
      data => {console.log(data);this.user$ = data}
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

@Adem, As Haijin comment, you must "work" a bit in subscribe parameter. The idea is that you subscribe to get the parameter, and, when you have the parameter, you ask about the user. But you need to make in the same step using switchMap

```
ngOnInit()
{ 
  //You subscribe the param. When you have ask for the user
  this.route.params.subscribe( params => 
      {
        this.user$ = params.id;
        //In subscribe you ask for the user
        this.data.getUser(this.user$).subscribe(
            data => this.user$ = data
        )
      });
}
```

Well, really In Angular is better don't subscribe two times else using Rjxs and switchMap

```
ngOnInit()
{ 
  //You subscribe the params, but you don't want the param
  this.route.params.pipe(
      switchMap(params => 
      {  //you want return the user
        return this.data.getUser(params.id)
      })
  ).subscribe(data => this.user$ = data)
}
```

Comment: I changed my `ngOnInit()` method in the details component to each of these suggestions and neither changed the behavior.